# How to put spaces between the Integers only in a string

Tags: android, string

I am having a string as "New Delhi, Delhi 110016"

Now I want to put spaces between each and every digit in the above string so that i will get the following result:-

"New Delhi, Delhi 1 1 0 0 1 6 "

Guys please help me ..Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String s = "New Delhi, Delhi 110016";

System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?=[0-9]+)", "$0 "));
```

Output: `New Delhi, Delhi  1 1 0 0 1 6`

see example here: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/pQ8eik)

`(?=)` -  positive look ahead

**[EDIT]**

as alfasin noticed, I have extra space between text and numbers group.

changed it to:

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?=[0-9]+).", "$0 ").trim());
```

Comment: LOL, I would have given this nice answer +1 but he "cheated" - there is an extra space before the first digit which wan't mentioned in the answer while the requirement was specifically to add a space only between the digits!

Comment: @RGraham that's called "lookahead" - it finds a match without consuming the string - google it up and you'll find plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done easily:

```
String text = "New Delhi, Delhi 110016";
System.out.println("text = " + text.replaceAll("(\\d)","$1 ").trim());
```

OUTPUT:

```
text = New Delhi, Delhi 1 1 0 0 1 6
```

*Comment*: 
I used `trim()` to remove the extra space at the end of the string - but most of the chances are that it's not needed (the example output you provided in your question also has a trailing space after the last digit!).

Answer (score -1):

```
String test = "New Delhi, Delhi 110016";
for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
    test=test.replace(String.valueOf(i) , String.valueOf(i)+" ");
}
```